# pdoc3- ValueError: File or module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, pdoc

I'm using `pdoc` to generate documentation for one of my projects. This is my file structure-

```
my_project
|- files
|- logs
|- scripts
   |- __init__.py
   |- main_script.py
   |- script_one.py
```

..where the `main_script.py` imports `script_one.py` and a few other libraries. And the `__init__.py` is empty.

*From inside `my_project/` directory*, I run `pdoc3 --html scripts` and face the following error-

**`ValueError: File or module 'scripts.main_script' not found`**

.
.
.

I run `pdoc3 --html scripts/main_script.py` and face the following error-

**`ImportError: Error importing 'scripts/script_one.py': No module named 'random_module'`**

.
.
.

*From inside `scripts/` directory*, when I run `pdoc3 --html main_script.py`, it throws me an import error like-

```
ImportError: Error importing 'main_script.py': No module named 'some_module'
```

But it generates the doc as soon as I remove the `some_module` from my `main_script.py`.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar problem.

My folder structure is similar to that of the original question, but with extra script folders. When running `pdoc script_name.py` inside each of those folders some files gave me the error

**`ImportError: Error importing 'module_name.py': No module named 'module_name'`**

I was able to fix those by making sure all the routes were right and, for some reason, changing the order of imports. Try importing first all your files and then the rest (such as numpy, pandas, ...)

The one thing I haven't been able to solve is that, althought I can generate the documentation for all individual files, one (and only one) of the folders still gives me the error

**`ValueError: File or module 'script_folder..module_name' not found`**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the PYTHONPATH env variable includes the folder with the modules.  See
[pdoc-no-module-named-xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017196/pdoc-no-module-named-xxx)

Answer (score 0):

make sure pdoc3 is installed in separate virtual environment.
set environment variables for the root folder example folderx
After exporting the path of the folderx use this

pdoc3 --html folderx

to generate pyfiles of folderx as documents in a folder called html